# Hoping To Speed Up Slow R Query - tidyverse/dplyr/lubridate etc

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, lubridate

I've written a query in R on a large-ish data frame (200k rows, about 50 columns)

Small reprex:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df <- data.frame(index  = c(1, 1, 1, 1,
                            2, 2, 2, 2),
                 date_1 = as.Date(c("2020-01-01", "2021-01-01", "2022-01-01", "2023-01-01",
                                    "2020-07-01", "2021-07-01", "2022-07-01", "2023-07-01")))

df <- df %>%
  group_by(index) %>%
  mutate(date_2 = lead(date_1) %m-% days(1)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

It's very slow. The `group_by()` stage (which is important) on my real life data frame chops it up into about 40-50k groups.

Is there any easy way to speed this up pls? (preferably using `tidyverse` stuff). I'm wondering if the slowness is likely to be because of the `group_by()`, the `lead()` or the `lubridate` stuff (`%m-% days(1)`)

Thank you.

Comment: Your bigger slow-down is using `lubridate`, where changing from `lead(date_1) %m-% days(1)` to `lead(date_1) - 1` produces a 10x speed improvement. Otherwise, your R code is about as good as it can be in dplyr. If you need speed, it's possible that `data.table` might provide a slight speed advantage using `data.table`. I expanded your data 200x and benchmarked, and `data.table` was only about 14% faster, not huge, and might be less-so when dplyr-1.1.0 is finally released for r-release (4.2) (currently it is only available in binary for r-devel (4.3).

Comment: Maybe using `ave` can improve the speed: `df$date2 <- ave(df$date_1, df$index, FUN = \(x) lead(x) %m-% days(1))`

Comment: if you still need to speed the processing up after all optimization on the code and have more than one core available, parallel processing can help alot (not allways the case depending on the code and data structure). There is a nice tidyverse implementation picking up on the purrr package (split your data to a list by group to get the proper data input for purrr/furrr): https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/10/furrr-0-2-0/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's difficult to benchmark "well" on data this small, I'll explode a bit:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
df200 <- bind_rows(lapply(1:200, function(i) transform(df, index = index+2*i)))
df200DT <- as.data.table(df200)

out1 <- df200 %>%
  group_by(index) %>%
  mutate(date_2 = lead(date_1) %m-% days(1)) %>%
  ungroup()
out2 <- df200DT[, date_2 := shift(date_1 %m-% days(1), type="lead"), by = index]
all.equal(out1, out2, check.attributes = FALSE)
# [1] TRUE
```

Simple benchmark reveals slight differences. (Note that I used two different R sessions to be able to compare dplyr-1.0.10 with dplyr-1.1.0, recently released with some big changes.)

```r
bench::mark(
  # in a different process
  dplyr_1.0.10 = df200 %>% group_by(index) %>% mutate(date_2 = lead(date_1) %m-% days(1)) %>% ungroup(),
  # in this process :-)
  dplyr_1.1.0 = df200 %>% group_by(index) %>% mutate(date_2 = lead(date_1) %m-% days(1)) %>% ungroup(),
  dt = df200DT[, date_2 := shift(date_1 %m-% days(1), type="lead"), by = index], 
  check = FALSE, min_iterations = 50)
# Warning: Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is disabled.
# # A tibble: 2 × 13
#   expression       min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory                 time            gc               
#   <bch:expr>  <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list>                 <list>          <list>           
# 1 dplyr_1.0.10   360ms    374ms      2.63     594KB     14.5    50   275        19s <NULL> <Rprofmem [1,706 × 3]> <bench_tm [50]> <tibble [50 × 3]>
# 1 dplyr_1.1.0    350ms    369ms      2.62     594KB     19.3    50   368      19.1s <NULL> <Rprofmem [1,662 × 3]> <bench_tm [50]> <tibble [50 × 3]>
# 2 dt             295ms    310ms      3.17     298KB     19.9    50   315      15.8s <NULL> <Rprofmem [811 × 3]>   <bench_tm [50]> <tibble [50 × 3]>
```

So it doesn't appear to be something that dplyr-1.1.0 or data.table can improve by itself. However, if you remove the use of `%m-%`, you can get some significant improvements. (This works more easily with dates since subtraction of days is straight-forward ... if you are subtracting months, it becomes a little more problematic.)

```r
bench::mark(
  dplyr_1.1.0_nolubridate = df200 %>% group_by(index) %>% mutate(date_2 = lead(date_1 - 1L)) %>% ungroup(), 
  dt_nolubridate = df200DT[, date_2 := shift(date_1 - 1L, type="lead"), by = index], 
  ave = cbind(df200, date_2 = ave(df200$date_1, df200$index, FUN = \(x) dplyr::lead(x) %m-% days(1))),
  ave1 = cbind(df200, date_2 = ave(df200$date_1, df200$index, FUN = \(x) dplyr::lead(x) - 1)), 
  check = FALSE, min_iterations = 50)
> 
# Warning: Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is disabled.
# # A tibble: 4 × 13
#   expression                   min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory                 time            gc               
#   <bch:expr>              <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list>                 <list>          <list>           
# 1 dplyr_1.1.0_nolubridate   27.5ms   31.7ms     31.8      221KB     21.6    50    34      1.57s <NULL> <Rprofmem [467 × 3]>   <bench_tm [50]> <tibble [50 × 3]>
# 2 dt_nolubridate            5.77ms   6.62ms    137.     42.01KB     25.7    69    13   505.49ms <NULL> <Rprofmem [8 × 3]>     <bench_tm [69]> <tibble [69 × 3]>
# 3 ave                     360.27ms 399.78ms      2.48     5.6MB     18.1    50   366     20.18s <NULL> <Rprofmem [3,177 × 3]> <bench_tm [50]> <tibble [50 × 3]>
# 4 ave1                     38.47ms  45.15ms     20.9     5.28MB     23.0    50    55      2.39s <NULL> <Rprofmem [1,260 × 3]> <bench_tm [50]> <tibble [50 × 3]>
```

I added GKis' `ave` code for comparison, and I did not rerun dplyr-1.0.10 (since it did not appear to change much). Note that while `dplyr` is quite a bit faster without `lubridate`, the `data.table` solution is significantly faster without it, lending to its internal optimization of some code-paths.

Comment: @GKi, why'd you delete your answer? I was intend to add to it, not subsume it. I apologize if including benchmarks on your code was the issue, I'll happily remove it if you prefer!

Comment: It's all fine! I thought you just write a comment and want to initialize an answer (and made this also as a Wiki). Using ave is just cosmetic in this case.

Comment: Thank you for this. Yes, I've tried it myself and just doing -1 instead of %m-% days(1) does indeed speed things up more than 10x on my "real life" query. In fact there were a few other instances in my code where I had %m-% days(1) so I've edited all of those too.

Much appreciated.